# Eloquent ORM query of type Model (not Collection)

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, eloquent

I'm trying to get an object of type Model. I'm using Laravel 4.x with the Eloquent ORM.

If I do this, it doesn't work :

```
Liveshow::where('slug', $slug)->get();
```

And if I do this, it works and returns the Model object :

```
Liveshow::find(Liveshow::where('slug', $slug)->pluck('id'));
```

**I'm wondering if there is a better way to go.**

I need the Object to be of type Model because I'm doing this after :

```
    $userLiveshow = new UserLiveshows;
    $userLiveshow->user()->associate($user);
    $userLiveshow->liveshow()->associate($liveshow);
    $userLiveshow->started_at = Carbon::now();
    $userLiveshow->watched = 0;
```

Thanks for your help.

John

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you expect only one model to match your query and therefore don't want a collection as result, just use `first()`:

```
$liveshow = Liveshow::where('slug', $slug)->first();
```

Comment: Of course... Thanks very much ! Thought my query was not pretty enough for Laravel ;)